# compareTo java method on Strings return value

Tags: java, comparable

One way to compare Objects string properties in java is by implementing the comparable interface.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String surname;
    private String firstname;

    public Person(String surname, String firstname) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        int compareResult = this.surname.compareTo(person.surname);
        if (compareResult == 0)
            return this.firstname.compareTo(person.firstname);
        return compareResult;
   }
```

If the objects are equal, the program returns 0.
Else the program returns a negative integer

Ex:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Joe", "Rock");
Person person2 = new Person("Joe", "Stone");

person1.compareTo(person2)
```

return: -17

What is the reason behind the negative integer?

Note: In case the Strings in the object are changing and not equal, the negative number will be different to what it is now.

Comment: it isn't always negative, it depends on which of the values of greater. Here's a quick read on the topic: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_compareto.asp#:~:text=The%20compareTo()%20method%20compares,equal%20to%20the%20other%20string.

Comment: What is the java implementation you use? For that particular example, the return value should be the same as `"Rock".compareTo("Stone");` which is `-1`.

Comment: Comparable isn't used to check if two Objects are equal or not. That is done with the equals method. Comparable is used for introducing a natural order where it return if an object should be sorted before, after or on the same level as another object. To represent those 3 possible return values (before, after and same) it was decided to use a number where those 3 different states are represented by a negative number, positive number and zero.

Comment: official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) of `compareTo()`: *"**Returns:**...a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument..."*